# R - loop through multiple dataframes from a list of names

Tags: r, loops

I have a number of large DFs and I want to loop through them. Instead of binding them together to make a big list I thought I should make a simple vector with their names and look though them, but how can I do this?

For example I have:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(c("a", "b", "c"),c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
DF2 <- data.frame(c("aa", "bb", "cc"),c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
DF3 <- data.frame(c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"),c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))

MyDFs <- c("DF1", "DF2", "DF3")

for (i in MyDFs) {
    print(nrow(i))
}
```

but the for loop does not work as R does not recognise them as the DFs, how can I correct this? also is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Your data.frames should be in a list to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or

```
 sapply(mget(MyDFs),nrow)
 #DF1 DF2 DF3 
 # 3   3   3
```

If you don't want to create a vector `MyDFs`

```
 sapply(mget(ls(pattern="DF")), nrow) #should also work
```

Answer (score 0):

In your own code, just replace   `print(nrow(i))`  with `print(nrow(get(i)))`, since i is:  chr "DF1" etc.

```
for (i in MyDFs) {
     print(nrow(get(i)))
}
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
```